# What types of numbers are representable in binary floating-point?

Tags: math, language-agnostic, floating-point

I've read a lot about floats, but it's all unnecessarily involved. I *think* I've got it pretty much understood, but there's just one thing I'd like to know for sure:

I know that, fractions of the form `1/pow(2,n)`, with `n` an integer, can be represented exactly in floating point numbers. This means that if I add `1/32` to itself 32 million times, I would get exactly `1,000,000`.

What about something like `1/(32+16)`? It's one over the sum of two powers of two, does this work? Or is it `1/32+1/16` that works? This is where I'm confused, so if anyone could clarify that for me I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The rule can be summed up as this:

- A number can be represented exactly in binary if the prime factorization of the denominator contains only 2 (i.e., the denominator is a power-of-two).

So `1/(32 + 16)` is not representable in binary because it has a factor of 3 in the denominator. But `1/32 + 1/16 = 3/32` is.

That said, there are more restrictions to be representable in a floating-point type. For example, you only have 53 bits of mantissa in an IEEE `double` so `1/2 + 1/2^500` is not representable.

So you can do sum of powers-of-two as long as the range of the exponents doesn't span more than 53 powers.

---

To generalize this to other bases:

- A number can be exactly represented in base 10 if the prime factorization of the denominator consists of only 2's and 5's.
- A rational number `X` can be exactly represented in base `N` if the prime factorization of the denominator of `X` contains only primes found in the factorization of `N`.

Comment: So if I've got that right, I can use any number `X/Y` as long as `Y` is a power of 2 and `X` is a number less than `2^53`?

Comment: @Mysticial: +1 for the answer, but I've a doubt. 24/48 = 0.5, however by the above rule, it shouldn't be representable since 3 is one of the prime factors of 48, which isn't one of 10's prime factor. Why?

Comment: @legends2k 24/48 is reducible. You should reduce your fraction before trying to apply the above rule.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: Aah, got it, the numbers should be coprime integers [gcd(X, Y) = 1] for the rule to work.

Answer (score 10):

A finite number can be represented in the common IEEE 754 double-precision format if and only if it equals M•2<sup>e</sup> for some integers M and e such that -2<sup>53</sup> < M < 2<sup>53</sup> and -1074 ≤ e ≤ 971.

For single precision, -2<sup>24</sup> < M < 2<sup>24</sup> and -149 ≤ e ≤ 104.

For double-precision, these are consequences of the facts that the double-precision format uses 52 bits to store a significand (which normally has 53 bits due to an implicit 1) and uses 11 bits to store an exponent. 11 bits encodes numbers from 0 to 2047, but 0 and 2047 are excluded for special purposes, and the encoded number is biased by 1023, so it represents unbiased exponents from -1022 to 1023. However, these unbiased exponents are for significands in the interval [1, 2), and those significands have fractions. To express the significand as an integer, I adjusted the exponent range by 52. Single-precision is similar, with 23 bits to store a 24-bit significand, 8 bits for the exponent, and a bias of 127.

Expressing the representable numbers using an integer times a power of two rather than the more common fractional significand simplifies some number theory and other reasoning about floating-point properties. I used it in this answer because it allows the set of representable values to be expressed concisely.

Comment: See this is exactly the kind of "too deeply involved" I mentioned in my question...

Comment: @Kolink: The answer itself is a single sentence that states exactly which numbers can and cannot be represented, using only the familiar concepts of integers, multiplication, powers, and less-than (or equal to). How much simpler than that can you get? You have an integer times a power of two, and the integer and the power have to be within certain bounds. The rest of the answer is just explanation about where the sentence comes from.

Answer (score 4):

Floating-point numbers are literally represented using the form:

```
1.m * 2^e
```

Where `1.m` is a binary fraction and `e` is a positive or negative integer.

As such, you can represent `1/32 + 1/16` exactly, as:

```
1.1000000 * 2^-4
```

(`1.10` being the binary fraction equivalent to 1.5.) `1/48`, however, is not representable in this format.

Comment: (I think you mean `1.m * 2^e`.)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `1.1000000 * 2^-4`?

Answer (score 0):

One point not yet mentioned is that semantically, a floating-point number may be best regarded as representing a range of values.  The range of values has a very precisely-defined center point, and the IEEE spec generally requires that the result of a floating-point computation be the number whose range contains the point one would get operating upon the center-points of the original numbers, but in the sequence:

```
  double N1 = 0.1;
  float  N2 = (float)N1;
  double N3 = N2;
```

N2 is the unambiguous correct single-precision representation of the value that had been represented in N1, despite the language's silly requirement to use an explicit cast.  N3 will represent one of the values that N2 could represent (the language spec happens to choose the `double` value whose range is centered upon the middle of the range of the `float`).  Note that while N2 represents the value of its type whose range contains the correct value, N3 does not.

Incidentally, conversion of a number from a string to a float in .net and .net languages seems to go through an intermediate conversion to `double`, which may sometimes alter the value.  For example, even though the value 13571357 is representable as a single-precision float, the value 13571357.499999999069f gets rounded to 13571358 (even though it's obviously closer to 13571357).

Comment: 1. "language's silly requirement to use an explicit cast": Which language are you talking about? C doesn't require a cast here...

Comment: @glglgl: The cited example code would be valid in C, Java, or C#; the latter two languages both require the cast to `float`, though not to `double`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Comment 2. doesn't apply any longer, I thought about the string -> double -> float conversion, and it seems you are right here.

Comment: @glglgl: Since writing the above, I've decided that having conversions to `float` go through `double` would actually be a good thing *if* the allowable implicit conversion were `double` to `float` rather than the unfortunately-allowed `float` to `double`.  Among other things, if implicit conversions were allowed for `long`->`Decimal`->`double`->`float`, one could specify that, among built-in types, any sequence of implicit conversions from T to U to V would be equivalent to an implicit conversion directly from T to V.  Allowing an implicit conversion from `float` to `double` breaks that.