# sprintf seems to be rounding up?

Tags: c, printf

Something odd is occuring in my C code below.

I want to compare numbers and I round to 4 decimal places.

I have debugged and can see the data being passed in.

The value of `tmp_ptr->current_longitude` is 6722.31500000, and the value of `tmp_ptr->current_latitude` is 930.0876500000.

After using the sprintf statements:

```
charTmpPtrXPos = "6722.3150" and charTmpPtrYPos = "930.0876".
```

I expect the exact same results for speed_info->myXPos and speed_info->myYPos but strangely even though `speed_info->myXPos = 6722.31500000` and the value of `speed_info->myYPos > = 30.0876500000`, the sprintf statements

```
charSpeedPtrYPos= "930.0877"
```

So basically the sprintf statement behaves differently for the second value and appears to round it up. Having debugged this I know the input to the sprintf statement is exactly the same.

Can anyone think of a reason for this?

```
sizeOfSpeedList = op_prg_list_size (global_speed_trajectory);

tmp_ptr= (WsqT_Location_Message*)op_prg_mem_alloc(sizeof(WsqT_Location_Message));
tmp_ptr = mbls_convert_lat_long_to_xy (own_node_objid);

sprintf(charTmpPtrXPos, "%0.4lf", tmp_ptr->current_longitude);
sprintf(charTmpPtrYPos, "%0.4lf", tmp_ptr->current_latitude);

speed_info = (SpeedInformation *) op_prg_mem_alloc (sizeof (SpeedInformation));
for (count=0; count<sizeOfSpeedList; count++)
{
    speed_info = (SpeedInformation*) op_prg_list_access (global_speed_trajectory, count);

    sprintf(charSpeedPtrXPos, "%0.4lf", speed_info->myXPos);
    sprintf(charSpeedPtrYPos, "%0.4lf", speed_info->myYPos);

    //if((tmp_ptr->current_longitude == speed_info->myXPos) && (tmp_ptr->current_latitude == speed_info->myYPos))
    if ((strcmp(charTmpPtrXPos, charSpeedPtrXPos) == 0) && (strcmp(charTmpPtrYPos, charSpeedPtrYPos) == 0))
    {
        my_speed = speed_info->speed;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: what are the respecive variable types? `float`? `double`? `long double`?

Answer (score 4):

`printf()` typically rounds to the nearest decimal representation, with ties sent to the “even” one (that is, the representation whose last digit is 0, 2, 4, 6, or 8).

However, you must understand that most numbers that are finitely representable in decimal are not finitely representable in binary floating-point. The real number `930.08765`, for instance, is not representable as binary floating-point. What you really have as a `double` value (and what is converted to decimal) is another number, likely slightly above `930.08765`, in all likelihood `930.0876500000000532963895238935947418212890625`. It is normal for this number to be rounded to the decimal representation `930.0877` since it is closer to this representation than to `930.0876`.

---

Note that if you are using Visual Studio, your *printf() functions may be limited to showing 17 significant digits, preventing you from observing the exact value of the `double` nearest `930.08765`.

Comment: Pretty sure you are right that the number isn't really 930.08765 . I find it helpful to subtract a known (and "representable") number in order to see additional digits. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12124973/1967396 for figuring out what numbers you need to subtract...

Comment: @Floris Apart from 0.5, fractional floating-point numbers have their decimal digits end in …25 or …75. So it is certain that the floating-point number involved isn't 930.08765, but it really helps to have conversions functions that work beyond the first 17 digits, if only to see what the real value of the `double` is. I would chalk up the oversight in Visual Studio to the superstition that floating-point numbers do not represent exact values (they do. What you use them for is your problem, but they represent exactly values such as 930.0876500000000532963895238935947418212890625).

Comment: @PascalCuoq: I would attribute the limitation in MSVC more to laziness or being performance-oriented than superstition, although the latter may play a big part in programmers' misconceptions around it. Writing a `printf` implementation that can give exact output for arbitrary values and that can correctly round past a limited number of digits (e.g. 17) is nontrivial, and it's hard to make the performance match an implementation that's oriented towards the limited results without just including two different implementations and choosing one based on the requested precision.

Answer (score 2):

**It is the difference between a `float` and a `double`.**

OP is likely using `tmp_ptr->current_latitude` as a `float` and `speed_info->myYPos` as a `double`.  Suggest OP use `double` though-out unless space/speed oblige the use of `float`.

```
int main() {
  float  f1 = 930.08765;
  double d1 = 930.08765;
  printf("float  %0.4f\ndouble %0.4f\n", f1, d1);
  return 0;
}

float  930.0876  
double 930.0877
```

---

As the typical `float` uses a IEEE 4-byte binary floating point representation, `f1` takes on the exact value of
930.087646484375
930.0876  (This is the 4 digit printed result)
This is the closest `float` value to 930.08765.

Like-wise, for a `double`, `d1` takes on the exact value of
930.0876500000000532963895238935947418212890625
930.0877  (This is the 4 digit printed result)

In general, one *could* use more decimal places to reduce the likely-hood of this happening with other numbers, but **not** eliminate it.

---

Candidate quick fix

```
sprintf(charSpeedPtrYPos, "%0.4lf", (float) speed_info->myYPos);
```

This would first convert the value from `speed_info->myYPos` to a `float`.  As non-prototyped parameters of type `float` are converted to `double` before being passed to `sprintf()`, the value would get converted back to `double`.  The net result is a loss of precision in the number, but the same string conversion results.

```
printf("(float) double  %0.4f\n", (float) d1);
// (float) double  930.0876
```

---

BTW: The `l` in `"%0.4lf"` serves no code generation purpose.  It is allowed though.

Answer (score 0):

See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

A dot followed by a number specifies the precision, which is 4 in your case. Try to use a higher presicion if you need it. I have tried your number with a precision of 5 and it isn't rounded up anymore. So it should be..

```
sprintf(charSpeedPtrYPos, "%0.5lf", speed_info->myYPos);
```

..or any higher number which fits your needs.