# C++ floating-point console output issue

Tags: c++, io

```
float x = 384.951257;
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(6) << x << std::endl;
```

The output is 384.951263. Why? I'm using gcc.

Comment: As i see `setprecision` is not member of std namespace. so it should not run first. How it is giving output for you?
and yes it is giving that output because maybe compiler is rounding off the float value.

Comment: @RavindraGupta `#include <iomanip>` and it's there.

Answer (score 8):

`float` is usually only 32-bit. With about 3 bits per decimal digit (2<sup>10</sup> roughly equals 10<sup>3</sup>) that means it can't possibly represent more than about 11 decimal digits, and accounting for other information it also needs to represent, such as magnitude, let's say 6-7 decimal digits. Hey, that's what you got!

Check e.g. Wikipedia for details.

Use `double` or `long double` for better precision. `double` is the default in C++. E.g., the literal `3.14` is of type `double`.

Comment: Excellent explanation! Just one question I have, how many decimal places will be taken by 'sign' or '.' (I want to understand what is this 11 - 7 or 8)

Comment: @Digital_Reality: e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Basic_formats

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: The problem isn't precision here, but that not all decimal fractions are fully representable in binary number system (see my answer). Using `double` and `long double` won't help too. [See here](http://ideone.com/8JzUpz).

Comment: @legends2k: you're right that not all decimal fractions are fully representable with binary floating point, wrong that the problem isn't precision, and wrong that `double` or `long double` won't help.

Comment: Can you please enlighten me on the wrong parts? Even if you had infinite precision, you cannot completely represent 0.1 in binary. [This page](http://cs.furman.edu/digitaldomain/more/ch6/dec_frac_to_bin.htm) describes it with calculations. Of course, with wider precision data-types, one can get good approximations but doesn't mean that one can represent them completely.

Comment: @legends2k: Oh, my pleasure. Let's first examine: " Using double and long double won't help". If you change the OP's code to use `double`, then (with e.g. g++) you get the output `384.951257`, so it *does* help. But why? The displayed value is an approximation to the internal one, which in turn is an approximation to the value specified in the source code. But with `double` the approximations are good enough to get correct digits all the way, for the relevant number of them. :-)

Comment: Well, I think this can be argued eitherways, I'll stop here :)

Comment: @legends2k: re the rest after "enlighten", that seems to be correct, but of course entirely irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Floats have a limited resolution. So it gets rounded when you assing the value to `x`.

Answer (score 2):

All answers here talk as though the issue is due to floating-point numbers and their capacity, but those are just implementation details; the issue is deeper than that. This issue occurs when representing decimal numbers using binary number system. Even something as simple as [0.1)<sub>10</sub> is not precisely representable in binary](http://floating-point-gui.de/formats/binary/), since [it can only represent those numbers as a finite fraction where the denominator is a power of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12124936/183120). Unfortunately, this does not include most of the numbers that can be represented as finite fraction in base 10, like 0.1.

The single-precision `float` datatype usually gets mapped to [*binary32*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) as called by the IEEE 754 standard, has 32-bits which is partitioned into 1 sign bit, 8 exponent bits and 23 significand bits (excluding the hidden/implicit bit). Thus we've to calculate upto 24 bits when converting to binary32.

Other answers here evade the actual calculations involved, I'll try to do it. This method is explained [in greater detail here](http://www.tfinley.net/notes/cps104/floating.html). So lets convert the real number into a binary number:

> Integer part 384)<sub>10</sub> = 110000000)<sub>2</sub> (using the usual method of successive division by 2)
>
> Fractional part 0.951257)<sub>10</sub> can be converted by successive multiplication by 2 and taking the integer part
>
> 0.951257 * 2 = 1.902514
>
> 0.902514 * 2 = 1.805028
>
> 0.805028 * 2 = 1.610056
>
> 0.610056 * 2 = 1.220112
>
> 0.220112 * 2 = 0.440224
>
> 0.440224 * 2 = 0.880448
>
> 0.880448 * 2 = 1.760896
>
> 0.760896 * 2 = 1.521792
>
> 0.521792 * 2 = 1.043584
>
> 0.043584 * 2 = 0.087168
>
> 0.087168 * 2 = 0.174336
>
> 0.174336 * 2 = 0.348672
>
> 0.348672 * 2 = 0.697344
>
> 0.697344 * 2 = 1.394688
>
> 0.394688 * 2 = 0.789376

Gathering the obtined fractional part in binary we've 0.111100111000010)<sub>2</sub>. The overall number in binary would be 110000000.111100111000010)<sub>2</sub>; this has 24 bits as required.

Converting this back to decimal would give you 384 + (15585 / 16384) = 384.951232)<sub>10</sub>. With the rounding mode (round to nearest) enabled this comes to, what you see, 384.951263)<sub>10</sub>.

This can be [verified here](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/Decimal.html).