# Oh where has my precision gone with OpenMesh vector arithmetic?

Tags: c++, double

Using `double`s I would expect to have about 15 decimal points of precision. I know that many decimal numbers are [not exactly representable in floating point notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124936/what-types-of-numbers-are-representable-in-binary-floating-point), so I would get an approximation for `1/3` for example. However, using a `double` I would expect an approximation that was correct to about 15 decimal points. I would also expect to retain that level of accuracy when doing arithmetic.

However, in the following example, I try to calculate the area of a triangle using [Heron's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) and `OpenMesh::Vec3d` which are backed by [`OpenMesh::VectorDataT<double,3>`](http://www.openmesh.org/media/Documentations/OpenMesh-Doc-Latest/a00291.html) and end up with a result that is only accurate to 5 decimal points.

The correct result is `area = 8.19922e-8`, but I'm getting `area=8.1992238711962083e-8`. Any ideas where this is coming from?

The suggestion that this might result from the instability in Heron's Formula is a good one, but unfortunately is not the case in this example. I have added code which calculates the stable variation on Heron for those who might be interested. In this example, `u.norm()>v.norm()>w.norm()`.

```
#include <OpenMesh/Core/Mesh/PolyMesh_ArrayKernelT.hh>

int main()
{
    //triangle vertices
    OpenMesh::Vec3d x(0.051051, 0.057411, 0.001355);
    OpenMesh::Vec3d y(0.050981, 0.057337, -0.000678);
    OpenMesh::Vec3d z(0.050949, 0.057303, 0.0);

    //edge vectors
    OpenMesh::Vec3d u = x-y;
    OpenMesh::Vec3d v = x-z;
    OpenMesh::Vec3d w = y-z;

    //Heron's Formula
    double semiP = (u.norm() + v.norm() + w.norm())/2.0; 
    double area = sqrt(semiP * (semiP - u.norm()) * (semiP - v.norm()) * (semiP - w.norm()) ); 

    //Heron's Formula for small angles
    double areaSmall = sqrt((u.norm() + (v.norm()+w.norm()))*(w.norm()-(u.norm()-v.norm()))*(w.norm()+(u.norm()-v.norm()))*(u.norm()+(v.norm()-w.norm())))/4.0;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible you have a small angle triangle? If so, there is a known numerical stability issue: (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula#Numerical_stability)

Comment: "I would also expect to retain that level of accuracy when doing arithmetic.":  Be sure you know what "that level of accuracy" is here; naively expecting 15 accurate digits from a subtraction of two nearly-equal quantities is a recipe for disappointment.

Comment: You **need** to sort the sides in your updated code.

Comment: @tmyklebu The sides are sorted. `u.norm()=0.002`ish `v.norm()=0.001`ish and `w.norm()=0.0007`ish.

Comment: @tmyklebu Your point about arithmetic is a good one. From Wikipedia "For addition and subtraction, the result should have as many decimal places as the measured number with the smallest number of decimal places", so I shouldn't be expecting any precision at all since the result is several orders of magnitude smaller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any calculation involving subtraction will result in a loss of precision, if the values are at all close to each other. How many significant digits do you expect from this subtraction?

```
  1.23456789012345
- 1.23456789000000
  ----------------
  0.00000000012345
```

Both operands have 15 digits of precision, but the result only has 5.

Comment: And I suppose the rest of the mantissa is unreliably filled with whatever's lying around.

Comment: @2cents: Jesus, no.  It's filled with zeroes.  Filling it with garbage would be very, *very* unpleasant for people like me.  (In any event, this is not really what's going on in your example.)

Answer (score 3):

Heron's formula is numerically unstable. If you have a very "flat" triangle with small angles, the sum of the two small sides is almost the long side, so one of the terms gets very small. If, for example, `a` and `b` are the small sides,

```
(s - c)
```

will be very small, because

```
s = (a + b + c)/2
```

is nearly equal to `c`.

The [wikipedia article about herons formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) mentions a stable alternative:

Arrange the sides such that `a > b > c` and use

```
A = 1/4*sqrt((a + (b + c))*(c - (a - b))*(c + (a - b))*(a + (b - c)))
```

Comment: I have tested this for my triangle, and it doesn't change the result. I will add the code to my question.

Comment: Did you use all the parentheses exactly as written here? They are very important for the stability.

Comment: Hmm, I would use the stable formula anyway, but yes, it seems this particular triangle doesn't suffer from the instability, and the other interesting answers are more relevant for this example.

Answer (score 3):

To 75 decimal places, the correct area of your triangle is

```
0.000000081992238711963087279421583920293974467992093148008322378721298327364.
```

If I replace the nine `double` constants you have with their decimal equivalents, I get

```
0.000000081992238711965902754749500279615357792172906541206211853522524016959
```

It would appear that you are not getting what you're expecting because you're expecting something unreasonable.

Comment: I guess my expectation was based on C++ keeping track of signifigant figures which of course it doesn't do. I was comparing my results to thoose from WolframAlpha which does. I suppose they simply truncate (or round) after 6 digits because that is what is significant.

Comment: Side note:  Learn how to use gmp.  Its C++ interface can make precision issues much, much easier both to track down and to rule out.

Comment: If I could accept two answers, I would also accept this one.