# Floating point numbers inaccuracy?

Tags: c, floating-point

I am prompting the user to input a float number. I save the number in float variable and multiply it by 100 to make it integer. Only 2 decimal places are allowed so it is a fairly easy thing. Now the strange part :

1. User Input : 0.1 -> Output : 100
2. User Input : 1.1 -> Output : 110
3. User Input : 1.5 -> Output : 150
4. **User Input : 2.1 -> Output : 209.999985**
5. User Input : 2.5 -> Output : 250
6. User Input : 3.8 -> Output : 380
7. **User Input : 4.2 -> Output : 419.999969**
8. User Input : 5.6 -> Output : 560
9. User Input : 6.0 -> Output : 600
10. User Input : 7.5 -> Output : 750
11. **User Input : 8.1 -> Output : 810.000061**
12. **User Input : 9.9 -> Output : 989.999969**

I tried this thing only till 10.00.

Referring [Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate) I got to know the reason behind this behavior, but isn't there any way to know which number would behave strangely?

Comment: That any person who knows programming would know. I meant to say is there any pattern in this?

Comment: It is not a 100 as result 0.1 is entered as there is a little  error.

Comment: No, it's not easy to predict ahead of time. But if a number can't be exactly expressed in binary, it will round to the nearest binary number, and you can expect that about 50% of the time it will round down rather than up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What types of numbers are representable in binary floating-point?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124936/what-types-of-numbers-are-representable-in-binary-floating-point)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to predict which numbers will do this, but most programmers don't really care.

You didn't specify the language you are using, but if you want to change something from a floating point representation into an integer representation, you usually have to do an explicit conversion using a function  like `Double.intValue()` or `Double.longValue()` in Java or a cast operator `(int)double_value;`

These techniques usually just cast off the fractional part of the number.  You may want to use a rounding function instead.  Again, in java that would be `Math.round()` as described in the [javadoc] (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html)

Answer (score 0):

I can only tell you with which numbers this will **not** happen:
With all numbers that can be represented exactly in binary, that is all numbers of the form:

```
N = Sum(i, 2^n(i))
```

or:

```
N = 2^n1 + 2^n2 + 2^n3 + ....
```

where `n(i)` are integers (positive or negative) from a limited range.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FLT_DIG` to print numbers within their matching decimal notation.

`FLT_DIG` to the number of leading decimal digits that a `float` will display and match its decimal assigned value.  It is at *least* 6.  In the below example, `2.1` can be printed to `2.10000e+00` which is 6 significant digits. `990.0` can be printed to `9.90000e+02` which is also 6 significant digits.

```
printf("%.*e", FLT_DIG - 1, 2.1f);  // 2.10000e+00
printf("%.*e", FLT_DIG - 1, 990.f); // 9.90000e+02
```

When code does operations like multiplying by `100`, the `float` product may incur a round-off error.  C does not specify accuracy here, but an error of < 0.5 parts in 16 million can be expected.  With many operations, this eats into the number of reliable digits down from `FLT_DIG`.

In general, avoid expecting matching arithmetic and computer results finer than `FLT_DIG` digits.  If that is insufficient, use `double`, which is is at least good for at least 10 digits (and with typical `double`, is good for 15 digits - use `DBL_DIG`)

Note: `"%.5e"` direct `printf()` to print 1 digit before and 5 digits after the decimal point for a total of 6 significant digits.  That is the reason for `-1` in `printf("%.*e", FLT_DIG - 1, ...);`