# Check if a number is exactly representable as `f32`

Tags: rust, floating-point, ieee-754

I wondered whether the values 1/256, 2/256, 3/256, ... 254/256 and 255/256 are exactly representable as `f32`. Now, someone smart would think about how floating point numbers work and find out that way. But I would like to check that in a program. All numbers I want to check are fractions and I control the values (i.e. no user input).

I started with this:

```
for n in 1u8..=255 {
    let f = (n as f32) / 256.0;
    println!("{}", f);
}
```

But now what? I tried printing the number to see if there were a large number of recurring digits, but that doesn't always work. For example,  0.4 which is not exactly representable:

```
println!("{}", 0.4);     // prints "0.4"
println!("{:.20}", 0.4); // prints "0.40000000000000002220"
```

Here we have to manually crank up the precision to see the problems. And in any case, looking at the string output seems like a suboptimal solution anyway.

First I thought that there might be a method on `f32`, but this wouldn't make much sense, would it? Because when a `f32` already exists, there is no way to know if its value was intended or not. So we somehow have to find out when creating the float value and compare to the "idealized" value?

**Is there any way to check if a value can be exactly represented as `f32`?**

Comment: Here's a test that will "almost always" work, though it needs refining: You start with two arbitrarily large integers representing an irreductible fraction `a/b`. If `b` is not an exact power of 2 (i.e. `b` is not 1,2,4,8,...), then your number will not be exactly representable. If `a` is more than about 2^23 then it will not be exactly representable. Otherwise (i.e. if `a<2^23` and `b` is an exact power of 2), most likely it will be representable. However, I've skipped lots of quirks and it would be far from trivial to take everything into account.

Comment: @Jojonete That's very few values. Maybe f32 is not the encoding to use in this situation.

Comment: @Darth: why *very few values*? You have a numerator and a denominator. Only the denominator must be a power of 2, not the numerator, and then you have the possibility of using the exponent, so you have almost 2^32 possible values.

Comment: Some extra information to the comment of @Jojonete: (1) reduce `A/B` to an irreducible fraction is done using the greatest common divisor (`A/B =a/b` with `a=A/gcd(A,B)` and `b=B/gcd(A,B)`). (2) [check if `b` is a power of two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600293). (3) you have to fiddle around a bit with the exponent to figure out the range of `b`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124936/what-types-of-numbers-are-representable-in-binary-floating-point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type [`Rational`](https://docs.rs/rug/1.3.0/rug/struct.Rational.html) from the [`rug` crate](https://crates.io/crates/rug) can represent fractions exactly. It also implements `PartialEq<f32>` so you can compare the exact representation with your `f32` directly to check if they are equal.

```
for n in 1u8..=255u8 {
    let rat = Rational::from((n, 256));
    let f = (n as f32) / 256.0;
    println!("{}/256 -> {}", n, rat == f);
}
```

And as you can see from the output, the numbers you want to test are indeed exactly representable as `f32`.

To get more a more interesting output, try `1 / n`:

```
for n in 1u8..=255u8 {
    let rat = Rational::from((1, n));
    let f = 1.0 / (n as f32);
    println!("1/{} -> {}", n, rat == f);
}
```

This shows that only fractions with a power-of-2 denominator are exactly representable.

Comment: Power-of-2 denominator is one rule. The other two rules are: the numerator has not too many bits (or it won't be representable in float significand) and the denominator power is not too high (causing float underflow). If denominator is 1, then numerator can have trailing 0 bits, but not too many (float overflow). See it implemented in Squeak Smalltalk http://source.squeak.org/trunk/Kernel-nice.853.diff. Here float are 64 bits, but that does not matter and is not hardcoded in the implementation of isAnExactFloat.

Answer (score 0):

Do the calculations you want with higher precision (`f64` is the obvious and fastest, but there are alternatives: e.g. [`f128`](https://docs.rs/f128/0.2.2/f128/), [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.diesel.rs/bigdecimal/index.html), [`rug`'s](https://docs.rs/rug/0.6.0/rug/) `rational` or `float`, [etc.](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/77x3m8/whats_the_best_crate_for_arbitrary_precision/)), and then check that the result is equal to itself converted to `f32` and back.

Assuming `f64` for the sake of example

```
d.is_finite() && (d as f32) as f64 == d
```

Of course, the result of these calculations may end up exactly representable as `f32` even if the exact result wouldn't be, as Jojonete's comment points out. So the datatype you want will depend on the calculations. E.g. for

> 1/256, 2/256, 3/256, ... 254/256 and 255/256

`rug::rational` would certainly be exact (so would `f64`, but then you need to "think about how floating point numbers work and find out that way" at least a bit).

Comment: This won't always work. Higher precision is not exact precision, so a number close enough to a f32 value will give a false positive. Say, `5 + 1E-1000` will give a false positive.

Comment: Yes, I should have clarified the limitation (though with `BigDecimal` this example should work).

Comment: Edited the answer.